# Insert an array into a single cell inside phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have 1 array :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "test role"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-16 03:22:06"
}
```

I want to display this array in a single cell in excel using Phpexcel?
Help me, please.
Sorry English I'm not good. I would like to thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't post an image that contains code. You should post direct code.

Comment: sorry this is the first time i ask : array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "test role"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-16 03:22:06"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Admin User"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-16 03:20:15"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "test role"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-19 02:00:10"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Admin User"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-19 01:56:44"
}

Comment: Yeah. no problem. Edit your question.